# T-SQL Overlapping time range parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to search for records that occurred in a specific time of day and between a date/time range.

**Example:**

My table:

```
ID | EmpID |  AuthorizationTime
-------------------------------
1  | 21455 | '23/01/2012 12:44'
2  | 22311 | '23/01/2012 18:15'
3  | 21455 | '23/01/2012 23:04'
4  | 10222 | '24/01/2012 03:31'
5  | 21456 | '24/01/2012 09:00'
6  | 53271 | '25/01/2012 12:15'
7  | 10222 | '26/01/2012 18:30'
8  | 76221 | '27/01/2012 09:00'
```

Sample SP input parameters:

```
@from:  22/01/2012 08:00
@to:    24/01/2012 23:00
@fromtime:  18:30
@totime:    08:00
```

Expected Output:

```
EntryID EmployeeID  AuthorisationTime
3       21455       '23/01/2012 23:04'
4       10222       '24/01/2012 03:31'
```

I've tried the following select statements in the SP:

```
...
Select @wAuthorizationTime=' AuthorizationTime between ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @from )+ ''' and ''' + convert(nvarchar(50),@to )+ ''' '

Select @Where = @wAuthorizationTime; Declare @wHours nvarchar(1000)='';
    if (ISNULL(@fromtime,'')<>'' and ISNULL(@ToTime,'')<> '') begin Select @wHours= ' (Cast(AuthorizationTime as time) between ''' + @fromTime + ''' and '''+ @ToTime +''')' 
    end if (@wHours <> '') Select @Where=@Where + ' and ' + @wHours

...
```

The problem with this statement is that I'm not getting any results if the end time is lower than the start time (e.g. 23:00 to 03:00).

It does work if I use a time frame that doesn't overlap (e.g. 18:00 to 23:59).

What I need to do to get above results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
select *
from Times
where AuthorizationTime >= @from
and AuthorizationTime <= @to
and (
        (@fromtime > @totime and ((cast(AuthorizationTime as time) between '00:00:00' and @totime) or 
                                  (cast(AuthorizationTime as time) between @fromtime and '23:59:59.999')
                                 )
        ) or
       (@fromtime <= @totime and cast(AuthorizationTime as time) between @fromtime and @totime)
    )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/694e31/2/1)

Answer (score 1):

Add a check to see if `@fromtime > @totime`. If that is the case, compare the TIME-casted value of AuthorizationTime like this:

```
(cast(AuthorizationTime as time) between '00:00:00' and @totime) or
(cast(AuthorizationTime as time) between @fromtime and '23:59:59.999')
```

Answer (score 0):

-- Do the complicated stuff before the SELECT statement

```
declare @from DateTime,
@to DateTime, 
@fromTime int,
@totime int

-- sample data:
    set @from = convert(datetime, '22/01/2012 08:00', 103)
    set @to = convert(varchar, '24/01/2012 23:00', 103)

-- first truncte the date
   set @from = convert(datetime, convert(varchar, @from, 103), 103)
   set @to = convert(datetime, convert(varchar, @to, 103), 103)

-- then build the time as an int: Hour * 100 + Minute
    set @fromTime = 1830 
    set @toTime = 800 -- note this is an int


-- Then use this to do the where clause:
    select *
    from myTable
    where AuthorisationTime between @from and @to
    and (DATEPART(HOUR, AuthorizationTime) * 100 + DATEPART(MINUTE, AuthorizationTime) 
         >= @fromTime OR 
          DATEPART(HOUR, AuthorizationTime) * 100 + DATEPART(MINUTE, AuthorizationTime) 
        <= @toTime)
```

I think this is easy to follow, test, and it is more likely to make use of indexes.

Comment: This doesn't work.  The point of the problem is that `@fromTime` is sometimes bigger than `@toTime`.  Plus, I tried it on the test data and it returned no rows.

Comment: @Jerrad, You are right, I had the fromTime and toTime backwards. I changed it in my answer.  Not sure if truncating the date was what you wanted either.

Comment: It's not my question, I'm just someone else that was working on an answer.  It's still not returning any rows, though. @JBrooks

Comment: I did.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Jerrad I also had the dates backwards (to, from). This is fixed now, I get 2 rows with your sample data. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: They aren't the right rows, though.  Seriously, fromTime is bigger than toTime.  He wants to see the times that are between 18:30 and 8:00 (crossing over the 24 hour boundry).

Comment: @Jerrad That is a simple change.